# Unable to Set Developer Mode

Tags: magento2, error, cli, developer-mode

I have strange issue when I am trying to set developer mode on my website.

When I tried to set developer mode with **CLI** and also changed **app/etc/env.php** it gave an error:

> **Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException:** Invalid Document Element 'plugin', attribute 'setOrder': The attribute 'setOrder' is not allowed. Line: 17 in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php:160

While We have not changed any core files since recently I upgraded Magento to 2.1.8 version, but still issue not resolved.

Comment: To identify the issue, temporarily disable the third part modules and try to set the mode one more time.

Comment: which edition you use, CE or EE??

Comment: We are using EE edition.

Comment: can anybody please help to resolve this issue?

Comment: Finally Resolved this issue,there was issue in our custom plugin that was not override properly.